# Nokogiri xpath() 'or' operator?

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

Is there a way I can accomplish the following using Nokogiri's `xpath()` ?

```
doc.xpath("//pod[@id=or('anid','anotherid')]")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `doc.xpath("//pod[@id='anid' or @id='anotherid']")`

Comment: perfect, that worked! That isn't XPath 2.0 syntax though, right?

Comment: @MarkF No it isn't, it's XPath 1.0. In XPath `or` works as an operand (like `something or something`), **not** as a function (like `or(something, something)`).

Answer (score 3):

Try this XPath:

```ruby
doc.xpath("//pod[@id='anid' or @id='anotherid']")
```

Answer (score 1):

This also worked for me:

```
sect_pr.xpath("//pod[@id='anid']", "//pod[@id='anotherid']")
```

It returns `NodeSet`

I got code like this:

```
sect_pr.xpath('//w:headerReference or //w:footerReference')
```

And it return `true` insted NodeSet